# how to write python script(like if ... else) in jenkis pipeline job

Tags: python, jenkins

pipeline {
    agent any
    stages {
        stage('authentication') {
            steps {
                sh '''
                    chmod 777 /var/run/docker.sock
                '''
                sh '''
                    sshpass -p 'actiontreerooster' scp -o StrictHostKeyChecking=no -o UserKnownHostsFile=/dev/null /mnt/gene3/jenkins-workspace/Build_Creation/resource/packages/* root@10.21.0.5:/mnt/gene3/

```
            '''
        }
    }
    stage('acquire') {
        agent { docker { image 'python:3.5.1' } }
        steps {
            python '''
                print("Python is fun.")

            '''
        }
    }
}
```

}

Answer (score 0):

You have to use either sh or bat while executing python, for your case it will by using the below:-

```
steps {
        sh "python --version"
        sh "python script.py"
      }
```